# how to store the data in hindi font in android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have trouble sending hindi characters from my android application to the server.

I have tried it several ways, but the result for an input like  `अगस्ता वेस्टलैंड का मामला आजकल` is `?????? ????????? ??` on the backend.

Invoking the service manually works just fine though.

Below you find the relevant part of my code, please review and advise:

```
s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_123);


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_ex4);
    s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_123);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.kuld);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Category = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            subcategory = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            comment = editText.getText().toString();
            foo1=Integer.toString(foo);

            new SendtoServer().execute();

            editText.setText(null);
            s1.setSelection(0);
            s2.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
}
```

SendtoServer:

```
class SendtoServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dlg;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dlg = new ProgressDialog(SpinnerEx4Activity.this);
        dlg.setMessage("Saving...");
        dlg.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CatId",comment));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subcategory", subcategory));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contents", comment));

        String result = new ServiceHandler().makeServiceCall("URL",2, nameValuePairList);
            Log.d("result =", result.toString());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dlg.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your ServiceHandler implementation too, since the problem most certainly relies in your request headers.

Comment: @rekaszeru Now My Problem has solved i used httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));   instead of httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));  thanks for every thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes in your `ServiceHandler`
write `HTTP.UTF_8` in place of `"utf-8"` and let me know.

Comment: i tried but its not working result coming again same. i got the point when i am sending the content to server that time its not changed thats the main motive to do in this application.